# HealthCheckUI not displaying the status of the dependencies like CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-2.2

I have asp.net core 2.2 project for building APIs. The APIs are dependent on few other services like Azure CosmosDB, Azure ServiceBus, Azure Storage services. I have the following code to implement the HealthCheck:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCustomHealthChecks(Configuration);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHealthChecks("/healthcheck", new HealthCheckOptions{Predicate = _ => true, ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse});
    app.UseHealthChecksUI();
}

public static IServiceCollection AddCustomHealthChecks(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var cosmosDBServiceEndPoint = configuration.GetValue<string>("CosmosDBEndpoint");
    var cosmosDBAuthKeyOrResourceToken = configuration.GetValue<string>("CosmosDBAccessKey");
    var cosmosDBConnectionString = $"AccountEndpoint={cosmosDBServiceEndPoint};AccountKey={cosmosDBAuthKeyOrResourceToken};";
    var hcBuilder = services.AddHealthChecks();
    hcBuilder.AddCheck("self", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy()).AddCosmosDb(connectionString: cosmosDBConnectionString, name: "CosmosDB-check", failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded, tags: new string[]{"cosmosdb"});
    services.AddHealthChecksUI(setupSettings: setup =>
    {
        setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Basic healthcheck", "http://localhost:63812/healthcheck");
    }

    );
    return services;
}
```

On validating the following Url:

http://localhost:63812/healthcheck

**Results:**

```
{
  "status": "Healthy",
  "totalDuration": "00:00:00.0277870",
  "entries": {
    "self": {
      "data": {},
      "duration": "00:00:00.0000026",
      "status": "Healthy"
    },
    "cosmosDB-check": {
      "data": {},
      "duration": "00:00:00.0276920",
      "status": "Healthy"
    }
  }
}
```

But on checking the HealthCheckUI I am not seeing CosmosDB as the dependency on the dashboard:
http://localhost:63812/healthchecks-ui#/healthchecks

[image]

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As the description show in the picture you provided, it seems that you use 3.0.x version package. So, if your project is asp.net core app 2.2, you need to use [AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI/2.2.35) 2.2.X and not 3.0.X versions.

Also, change

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    services.AddCustomHealthChecks(Configuration);
}
```

to

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddCustomHealthChecks(Configuration);
}
```

For more details, you could refer to how to [Implement health checks in ASP.NET Core services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/monitor-app-health#implement-health-checks-in-aspnet-core-services).

Comment: I did all the changes and also updated the code in the question. Sorry it was a typo mistake from my side. I did a validation once again and found not working for me.

Comment: You could check [HealthCheckUI and failure notifications](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#healthcheckui-and-failure-notifications)to troubleshoot.